# What Filenet P8 API will work with FileNet Cloud

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine, filenet-cpe

I currently have an application that uses the P8 FileNet .NET api to store files in our company's on-prem FileNet server.

The reference we add to our c# project is Filenet.Api.dll V. 5.111.0.470 . I believe it talks to the content engine.
[image]

I'm being told that the company wants to move to Filenet's cloud offering but that this API isn't compatible with it.

I'm having a hard time determining what API would be compatible with it. Or even if it's true that the .net API is not compatible.

Does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general this will most likely be GrapQl.
You could try from amazon cloud with a trial version.
https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-xxnek4yehitqi

Otherwise I would advice to contact IBM contactperson for your company to get insight in roadmap and api compatibility.